# Using notebook batteries as a no-break (UPS) for a desktop

Tags: ups, desktop-computer, battery

I have a notebook battery at home that became useless when my old notebook died (RIP). Can I use the battery in some way to implement something like a no-break (also known as UPS (Uninterruptible power supply)) for my father's desktop?

I know that I could have a really low break-energy safe time, but it would be really useful in the case that my father doesn't have a no-break/flywheel backup and I have a useless battery.

The main idea is to give some useful afterlife to this part of my old notebook. Is it possible to aggregate some control circuit with a notebook battery to the desktop's SMPS (Switched-mode power supply)?

Comment: This just sounds like a dangerous scenario.  Wire it wrong and the battery bursts into flames. . .

Comment: This would be off topic for Electronics. If you would like better answers, it's often helpful to not award the accepted answer in the first week, or even the first answer that comes along. You can remove the checkmark any time unless the answer is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not since the voltages are not similar. From the link below:

> A Li Ion pack consists of a number of the series/parallel connected
>   cells (typically from 4 to 16) to provide the required operating
>   voltage and current levels. Nominal voltage of each cell is typically
>   3.6-3.7 V, the charging voltage is about 4.2-4.3 V per cell. The
>   Li-ion phosphate cells have 2.9V nominal and 3.6V charging voltage.
>   Note that because of the cell's relatively high voltage, many
>   low-power portable products can operate from a single cell. Depending
>   on the cell connection scheme, the nominal Lithium Ion battery voltage
>   for a laptop computer can vary from 7.2 V to 14.8 V (typical voltages
>   for major brands are: 11.1 to 14.8 V for Dell laptops, 10.8 to 14.8 V
>   for Toshiba, Apple, Gateway and IBM laptops, 7.4 to 14.8 V for Sony,
>   7.2 to
>   14.8 V for HP, 14.4-14.8 V for Compaq). Note that the output voltage
>   rating of a laptop power supply is not necessarily the same as nominal
>   battery voltage.

http://www.smps.us/battery.html